# Sleep mode Arduino Due through IR receiver control

Tags: arduino-due, ir, remote-control, sleep

I need to put my Arduino Due into sleep mode in order to consume less power. My Arduino Due receives IR data and does some work with it, but I need to make it sleep until there is no data. If data appears it should wake up and do something with data and go back to sleep mode.

Is there any way to do this? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: you can't watch for data if the thing is off. you need another low-power thing to monitor the ir sensor and wake up the MCU if needed; i don't think the mcu itself can do that.

Comment: Connect the IR receiver to one of the interrupt pins, and set it so the mcu wakes up in the event of an interrupt.